# Strange behavior of dynamic objects

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have a simple control method `DoSomething` which receives a json string, converts it to a dynamic object and tries to get the data:

```
[HttpPost]
public string DoSomething(string jsonStr)  // {"0":null,"1":"loadData"}
{
     // In this case obj.GetType() = System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject
     object obj = Json.Decode(jsonStr); 

     // Correct, a == "loadData"
     var a = (obj as dynamic)["1"];          

     // Incorrect, compilation exception:
     // "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression 
     // of type 'System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject'"
     var b = (obj as DynamicJsonObject)["1"] 

     return "OK"; 
}
```

My question is why it is possible to access an indexer when I use an object as a dynamic object at the time when the original type doesn't have an indexer?

[image: Watches window]

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's a *really bad* short answer, and the internal representation isn't necessarily relevant at all. You could write a class with dynamic behaviour which responded to an indexer call without having a dictionary anywhere. Furthermore, that doesn't explain the compile-time/execution-time binding difference.

Comment: I decided that an obj has the same type in the runtime. I don't understand how it works, why it shows me different object behavior?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I'm afraid - I hope my answer has explained though... basically this is what dynamic binding is all about.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean obj is also inherits IDynamicMetaObjectProvider in all cases. It is the same object whether I use (obj as dynamic) or (obj as DynamicJsonObject). Why do I have an indexer access in the first case and don't in the another?

Comment: It's the same object, but when the compile-time type is `dynamic`, that means binding is done at execution time. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you're using all the infrastructure of `dynamic` - which doesn't just use reflection to find "real" members, but also uses `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` to provide support for members which are only known at execution time. This works because when you're using `dynamic`, the process of binding (working out what a member name means) is performed at execution time instead of at compile time.

In this case, it's the indexer which is being used at execution time - `DynamicJsonObject` doesn't declare an indexer, but overrides the [`TryGetIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex) method of `DynamicObject`. The meta-object provider implementation of `DynamicObject` will route indexer "get" calls via `TryGetIndex`.

A simpler example of this is `ExpandoObject`:

```
ExpandoObject foo = new ExpandoObject();
// This is invalid; the compiler can't find a Property member
foo.Property = "broken";

dynamic bar = foo;
// This is fine; binding is performed at execution time.
bar.Property = "working";
```

Comment: Ok. Do you mean `(obj as dynamic)["1"]` doesn't look like an indexer call in the MSIL?

Comment: @dyatchenko: Indeed it doesn't. Have a look!

Comment: Ok. I guess I got it. `(obj as dynamic)["1"]` - it is not indexer call, it is converted to `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` methods calls, right? If so, thank you!

Comment: @dyatchenko: Well, it's an indexer call in the source code, but it's compiled to calls via dynamic typing. (Check the IL for details.)